# how to set Bootstrap navbar active class in one page website in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am looking for solutions, but can't really understand. I'm new in Laravel and I want a simple instruction on how to set the active class in the bootstrap navbar on a [one-page website](http://w3public.com).

Here's what I've done so far, but can't get it done:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="{{Request::is('/')?'active':''}}"><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li class="{{Request::is('#about')?'active':''}}"><a href="{{ url('#about') }}">About</a></li>
            <li class="{{Request::is('#contact')?'active':''}}"><a href="{{ url('#contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have the solution and I would like to give you an example please give me the route what you made in web.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this using jQuery:

```
<!--Active class on click-->
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav li').click(function(){
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The fragment of a URL is only available client side, it is not sent to the server when a request is made, for example, if you make a request to:

```
https://example.com/example#example
```

The server will only know that you made the following request:

```
https://example.com/example
```

Therefore, if you would like to display the current active page in your single page application, you will need to make use of Javascript.

The easiest way to do this would be to listen for changes to the URL fragment (the `hash` in Javascript) and then add the class `active` to the element with the `hash` as its `href`.

1. Add the class `active` to the element that should be highlighted when default when the page loads (in this case, `home`).

   ```
   <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li><a class="active" href="/">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   ```
2. Add Javascript to listen to the `hashchange` event, and when that event happens you remove `active` from the current navigation item and add `active` to the newly selected navigation item, like so:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(){
       document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
       document.querySelector('[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').classList.add('active');
     });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your controller you can pass a active variable with name of the active page/menu.

eg.

```
// Your controller class...
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       // your logic here...
       $current = 'blog';

      return view('site.index', compact('current'));
    }
}
```

And in your menu:

```
<a href="#" class="{{ $current == 'blog' ? active : '' }}">Blog</a>
```

Or... A another alternative is directly in your view you capture a url segment from the current page/url existing in Request Class.

eg.

```
<a href="#" class="{{ Request::segment(1) == 'blog' ? active : '' }}">Blog</a>
```

The two ways will work. But, for me, the first option is more elegant and can be complemented with the [View::composer()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers) to share data with specific or all views.

Comment: You can call ```\Request::segments()``` to see all available segments from current request.

Comment: I am trying but it's still not working like <li class="{{ Request::segment(1) == '#about'?'active':''}}"><a href="{{ url('#about') }}">About</a></li>

Comment: #about not is a url segment, is a anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using named routes `->name('');`

and in your navbar just add `{{ Route::currentRouteNamed('') ? 'active' : ''  }}`

this is how your route should look I'm using dummy names for the example

`Route::get('/test', 'testController@index')->name('test.dashboard');`

this is how your link should look

`<li class="{{ Route::currentRouteNamed('test.dashboard') ? 'active' : ''  }}"><a href="{{ route('test.dashboard') }}">Test Dashboard</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap 5.0

```
$(function() {
    let pathname = window.location.pathname
    let navItem = $( ".nav-item" )
    navItem.find(".active").removeClass("active");
    navItem.find(`[href="${pathname}"]`).addClass("active");
});
```