# how to set the selected menu is active in bootsrap laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

This is my code. How to set the selected menu is active in bootsrap laravel 8?

```
<!-- Sidebar-->
            <div class="bg-dark border-right text-light" id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <div class="sidebar-heading"></div>
                <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-light" href="/home">Dashboard</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-light" href="/sales">Sales</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-light" href="/product">Product</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have try this, but don't work

[Setting active class for menu items dynamically in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452808/setting-active-class-for-menu-items-dynamically-in-laravel)

[how to set Bootstrap navbar active class in one page website in Laravel 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308999/how-to-set-bootstrap-navbar-active-class-in-one-page-website-in-laravel-5-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-light @if(Request::segment(1) == 'home') active @endif"  href="/home">Dashboard</a>
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-light @if(Request::segment(1) == 'sales') active @endif"  href="/sales">Sales</a>
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-light @if(Request::segment(1) == 'product') active @endif"  href="/product">Product</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this statement must in class tag @if(Request::segment(1) == 'home')

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this .You can use `request()->path()` to get current url path without base url .if you need to compare entire url then  `fullUrl()` will be best solution

```
 <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-dark text-light {{(request()->path()=="home")?"active":null}}}"   href="home">Dashboard</a>
```